# trapping SIGABRT from perl on VMS

Tags: perl, vms, openvms, dcl, vax

Given kill.pl:

```
$SIG{INT} = sub { print "int\n" };
$SIG{TERM} = sub { print "term\n" };
$SIG{ABRT} = sub { print "abort\n" };

print "sleeping...\n";
sleep 60;
```

And kill.com:

```
$ perl kill.pl
```

And launching+aborting like so:

```
submit /log_file=kill.log kill.com

delete /entry=XXXXXX/noconfirm
```

The signal handlers do not get called. Similar code works on Linux when the process is killed.

kill.log just shows:

```
(19:58)$ perl kill.pl
sleeping...
%JBC-F-JOBABORT, job aborted during execution
```

I read the vmsperl documentation and tried some things from http://perldoc.perl.org/sigtrap.html. Is there a way to do this?

Note that if I call:

```
@kill.com
```

And do a CTRL+C, SIGINT is handled by kill.pl.

I added the perl tag in case someone knows if there is a way to tell perl to trap every signal which might be the one I'm interested in. My attempt was:

```
$SIG{$_} = \&subroutine for keys(%SIG);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not sending a signal to the process -- you're instructing the queue manager to delete the process, which it does.  I think the easiest way to do what you want is to use Perl to send the signal.  Submit your job as before and use:

```
$ show system/batch
```

to find the pid of the job.  You'll see something like this when the queue manager has assigned an entry of 572:

```
  Pid    Process Name    State  Pri      I/O       CPU       Page flts  Pages
00003EA1 BATCH_572       HIB      1      259   0 00:00:00.05       511    626  B
```

Send your signal like so to pid 0x3ea1, noting that the job notification indicates it completed rather than aborted:

```
$ perl -e "kill 'ABRT', 0x3ea1;"
$

Job KILL (queue SYS$BATCH, entry 572) completed
```

Look at your log file and you'll see these two lines at the end:

```
sleeping...
abort
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. My job wasn't showing up when I show system/batch but I think F$GETQUI("DISPLAY_ENTRY","JOB_PID",<entry number>) was giving me the PID from the entry number I get. Unfortunately, I couldn't get kill to send the abort signal through perl such that it gets trapped. I tried 16 (ABRT) and 15 (TERM) in place of "ABRT" but those didn't work. When I tried 9 "KILL", it did kill immediately but I can't trap that signal.

Comment: I don't know why it didn't work for you.  What version of Perl are you running?

Comment: v5.8.7 and upgrading isn't an option :(

Comment: I do think the Perl version is the problem.  5.8.7 is eight years old.  There've been quite a few changes to signal handling in that time.  If you have access to a C compiler, you can build a "private" Perl that doesn't interfere with anything else on your system.  Not sure what else to suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Is this an a VAX or Alpha system?  I believe your 'delete' call may not be throwing an abort signal to your running job.  Been too long since I've used it, but can't remember a tool that would throw a specific signal to a batch job - LIB$SIGNAL went from a process, not to it.  You should try trapping the remaining signals from the 'error-signals' list on the sigtrap doc.